# SQL get string from the user

Tags: sql

I need help with an SQL query where I have a table of products and I need to get a string value from the user and compare with all others to get all the products name similar with the user input.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Presumably you have an application with a user interface that the user is using? You need to find out how your application interacts with whatever version of SQL you have in order to write queries, and pass parameters to those queries. Read some documentation / take a tutorial if you haven't done this before. Without knowing what languages / products / application type etc you are using we can't give any specific advice. The only thing I'd say is you need to find out how to write "parameterised queries" in your particular programming language.

Answer (score -1):

you can try to use LIKE syntax

```
declare @user_input varchar(3) = ?;
select * from product where productcode like ('%'+@user_input+'%')
```

Comment: you don't even know what DBMS the user is using. Or what the user interface tool is. This is total guesswork. Also this example is highly likely to be susceptible to SQL injection if the value is not parameterised